# Is there a way to retrieve a meeting with no videoTeleconferenceId via /communications/onlineMeetings/

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

I created a meeting via POST /me/onlineMeetings (I still have the response) and now want to access it via

GET /communications/onlineMeetings

But it says i need a VTC conference id which is not present in my response...

Answer (score 1):

Currently the GET onlineMeetings API can only retrieve meetings that have been created using a VTC device.

Please view our [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more information.

We have a note -

"Note: The GET method is currently only supported for a VTC conference id. These IDs are generated for Cloud-Video-Interop licensed users and this method is used to get the details to join the meeting."